# Как удалить класс из секции на js при условии, что...?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="left-column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
<div class="block-categories hidden-sm-down">
<ul class="category-top-menu">
<li><a class="text-uppercase h6" href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<section class="background socialx"><div class="content-wrapper"><div class="block-social col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
<h2 class="socialxtext">We Are Social</h2>
<ul class="social-btns"><li class="btnx facebook"><a class="facebook faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Facebook"></a></li><li class="btnx twitter"><a class="twitter faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Twitter"></a></li><li class="btnx rss"><a class="rss faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Rss"></a></li><li class="btnx youtube"><a class="youtube faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="YouTube"></a></li><li class="btnx googleplus"><a class="googleplus faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Google +"></a></li><li class="btnx pinterest"><a class="pinterest faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Pinterest"></a></li><li class="btnx vimeo"><a class="vimeo faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Vimeo"></a></li><li class="btnx instagram"><a class="instagram faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Instagram"></a></li></ul>
</div></div></section>
</div>
```

Как написать на js: Если в div с id "left-column" содержится section с class "background", тогда удалить данный класс из секции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll("#left-column section.background").forEach(
  el => el.classList.remove("background")
);
```

Comment: Супер! У меня ещё такой вопрос, возможно ли в div id="left-column" вырезать тэги «<section class="background socialx"><div class="content-wrapper">» таким образом, чтобы внутренние тэги остались?

Comment: @VladimirRodichev Можно. Попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо. Если вас не затруднит, я создал новый, аналогичный вопрос. Посмотрите его, пожалуйста. Я на таких примерах волшебных, учусь новому и применяю. Спасибо, что есть люди такие как вы, которые делятся своими знаниями